# Using external .js files on a .php page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This code in index.php works and test(), which is defined in test.js produces the desired alert in the browser:

```
<?php 
    #include ('db.php');
    #$dataBase = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName", $dbUser, $dbPass);    
    #PREPARE AND TRY    
    #$statement = $dataBase->query('SELECT * FROM users');
    #$rowCount = $statement->rowCount();
    #echo 'There are currently ' . $rowCount . ' rows in the database'; 
?>
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <TITLE>title</TITLE>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ui/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="ui/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css" /> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/jquery-ui-config.css" />        
    </HEAD>
    <BODY>

        <div id = 'clickablebutton'>Button</div>

        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            //console.log('self invoke on document ready');
            $('#clickablebutton').click(function(){
                test();  //alerts "it works"
            });
        </script>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

However, when I remove whatever is in `<script>` tag and add the `onclick` attribute to `<div>` to look like

```
<div id = 'clickablebutton' onclick='test()'>Button</div>
```

the code does not work anymore - test() function is not run, yet no error are produced.

Why?

UPD:

1. test() function is in test.js
2. code in test.js:

   var test = function(){
   alert('Works!');
   };

Comment: If you put the `test()` function (`var test=.....`) into the PHP page instead of the listener, does it work?

Comment: @Ben Yes, it works if the code is placed into <script> tag in the .php file.

Comment: Are you certain that the `.js` file has a relative URL of `test.js` in that case?

Comment: @Ben 100% positive, it is in the same directory as index.php. Moreover, it somehow works with the event listener, if path would be wrong it would wold not launch, right?

Comment: If you are using chrome, check console for errors.. 
you might need to clear the cache.. Pressing Ctrl+R helps sometimes

Comment: Clear your cache and you will get it.

Answer (score 0):

There was a post in the thread, which for some reason got deleted. The suggestion was to explicitly state `javascript:test()` in the HTML.

Complete html for the div:

```
<div id = 'clickablebutton' onclick='javascript:test()'>Button</div>
```

This solved the problem and external .js is now apparently referenced correctly.

This is something very valuable I have learned!

Answer (score 0):

The external .js file might not be loaded before the DOM is ready. So it can't find the test function

You should either use jquery ready call, or use jQuery.holdReady() if you can't use jquery ready for some reason. ([Reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.holdReady/))

```
$.holdReady( true );
$.getScript( "test.js", function() {
  $.holdReady( false );
});
```

Comment: It would give me an error in the console if function cannot be referenced, right? I think in this case, since index file is a .php it was somehow needed to explicitly define the attribute of the html element.